# Using JSTL display currency code (USD, etc) in jsp page - locale dependant

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

**What I want to do**

Using JSTL in jsp page display currency code in front of the value depending on the locale used

```
USD 1,234.99

CAD 4,321.99
```

**What I am doing and get**

```
<fmt:setLocale value="${info.locale}" scope="session"/>

<fmt:formatNumber value="${price}" type="currency"/>
```

Using the above I get is currency Symbol '$' but not the code (USD)

```
$ 1,234.99

$ 4,321.99
```

I am trying to do this and it gives me the correct output

```
<fmt:formatNumber  pattern="USD #,###.##;USD -#,###.##" value="${value}" type="currency"/>
```

But for this I have to do for all locale manually

Is there a way I can achieve this using JSTL without doing it manually?

Any help and direction toward it will be appreciated.

Thank you for your help and time.

Comment: formatNumber has a currencyCode and a currencySymbol attributes: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/formatNumber.html

Comment: Thanks @JB-Nizet, I did tried earlier those attributes like this '<fmt:formatNumber currencyCode="USD" currencySymbol="$" value="${price}" type="currency"/>' and using each one separately as well but it still displays the currency ('$') and not USD/CAD I think with this attributes we can let the tag know that the currency is of which locale by using either attribute but still it displays the symbol

Comment: That's because the locale rules tell that, in that locale, the preferred way of displaying a currency is to show the currency symbol, and not the currency code. If you don't like that, you can simply trick it by specifying USD as the currency symbol.

Comment: Thanks again @JB-Nizet, it's a good idea but again will I not have to do it manually for each locale?

Comment: So, you want to use the currency of the locale, rather than the currency associated to the price being printed, is that right? I would create my own tag then: `<price value="${price}"/>`.

Comment: thanks for being so helpful @JB-Nizet, yes,that is correct I want to use currency of the locale, and in fact I have that in a custom tag which does something like this  
    <c:when test="${locale == 'en_US'}">
        <fmt:formatNumber  pattern="USD ###,###,###,###.##;USD -###,###,###,###.##" value="${value}" type="currency"/>
    </c:when>...  and thinking on your comment I was thinking to do this <fmt:formatNumber currencySymbol="${getCountryCode}" value="${value}" type="currency"/> is there a way to get the countryCode in JSTL?

Comment: You mean the currency code, right? You can get it by calling `NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale).getCurrency().getCurrencyCode()`

Comment: Thanks again @JB-Nizet NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale).getCurrency().getCurrencyCode() dosent work in JSTL need to use scriptlet if need to use this
and in a tag file cannot use this as it throws
<%@ page declarative cannot be used in tag file
need to find a way to get the currencyCode in JSTL

Comment: Thank you @JB-Nizet for now I m using this in tag file <c:choose>
    <c:when test="${locale == 'en_US'}">
        <fmt:formatNumber   currencySymbol="USD " value="${value}" type="currency"/>
    </c:when>
    <c:when test="${locale == 'en_CA'}">
         <fmt:formatNumber currencySymbol="CAD " value="${value}" type="currency"/>       
    </c:when>
....... 
    <c:otherwise>        
        <fmt:formatNumber value="${value}" type="currency"/>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose> and it works thanks a lot for your help JB-Nizel if you can add your comments in answer so I can mark it as the answer

Answer (score 0):

To show the currency code instead of the currency symbol please change your jstl code as follows

```
<fmt:formatNumber  pattern="USD #,###.##;USD -#,###.##" value="${value}" type="currency" currencySymbol="USD"/>
```